# iOS - Using NSTimer, The UIImageView Just update at first time

Tags: ios, uiimageview

All

When I using NSTimer to complete my task, I meet some problem. I need Some Help, thanks.

Here is the Problem.

When I am using the NSTimer to show animation on UIImageView. but the UIImageView just update at the first time when I run the code in my iphone4s, using xcode. when the UIImageView appear again, it does not update the image content.
I have checked the log, the timer is called every time, and the code is covered when it runs.

NSTimer:

```
if (networkStatusTimer == nil) {
        networkStatusTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(getcurrentNetworkDelayStatus) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The networkStatusImageView Initialization Part:

```
- (UIImageView *)networkStatusImageView
{
    if (nil == _networkStatusImageView) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(246, 12, 24, 8);
        _networkStatusImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        _networkStatusImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight | UIViewContentModeTop;

        UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"]];
        UIImageView *img2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"]];
        UIImageView *img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_whitehollow_1x"]];

        img2.left = img1.right;
        img3.left = img2.right;

        [_networkStatusImageView setNeedsDisplay];
        [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img1];
        [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img2];
        [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img3];
    }
    return _networkStatusImageView;
}
```

The Selector Code:

```
- (void) getcurrentNetworkDelayStatus {
    currentNetworkDelayTime = 0;
    [_networkStatusImageView removeAllSubviews];
    UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"]];
    UIImageView *img2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"]];
    UIImageView *img3 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (currentNetworkDelayTime == 0) { 
        if (currentISRed) {
            img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"];
            img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"];
            img3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"];
        } else {    // 显示红色实心
            img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"];
            img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"];
            img3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"];
        }
        currentISRed = !currentISRed;
    } else if(currentNetworkDelayTime > 0 && currentNetworkDelayTime <= 500){ 
        img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greensolid1X"]];
        img2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greensolid1X"]];
        img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greensolid1X"]];
    } else if(currentNetworkDelayTime > 500 && currentNetworkDelayTime <= 3000){   
        img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greensolid1X"]];
        img2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greensolid1X"]];
        img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greenhollow_1x"]];
    } else if (currentNetworkDelayTime > 3000){
        img1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greensolid1X"]];
        img2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greenhollow_1x"]];
        img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_greenhollow_1x"]];
    }

    img2.left = img1.right;
    img3.left = img2.right;

    [img1 setNeedsDisplay];
    [img2 setNeedsDisplay];
    [img3 setNeedsDisplay];
    [_networkStatusImageView setNeedsDisplay];

    [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img1];
    [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img2];
    [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img3];
    });
}
```

Comment: the setNeedsDisplay calls are not needed

Comment: likely your _networkStatusImageView is nil

Comment: lastly: why the dispatch_async?

Comment: Yes, I also didn't see the setNeedsDisplay works, I will remove the setNeedsDisplay calls. _networkStatusImageView is initialized before, It will not be nil. Code Below:

Comment: I think maybe the problem is for process synchronization. so I added the dispatch_async to update UI in the main thread.

Comment: good thinking, but the timer is called in the thread you call schedule. so if you schedule it in main thread, its called there

Comment: I think I have already put all the things in the main thread, but Why the UI not updated... It confuses me for two days until now. I am really confused. I have searched the whole google and etc.

Comment: I added a new answer, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the function gets called you set the `currentNetworkDelayTime` to 0. Which means that only the:

```
if (currentNetworkDelayTime == 0) { 
    if (currentISRed) {
        img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"];
        img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"];
        img3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redhollow_1x"];
    } else {    // 显示红色实心
        img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"];
        img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"];
        img3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talk_icon_redsolid_1X"];
    }
    currentISRed = !currentISRed;
}
```

Gets called. So you need to change the line `currentNetworkDelayTime = 0;` to `currentNetworkDelayTime++;`

And you don't have to add the images to the current `UIView` every time, just create them one time in ex. `viewDidLoad` and make a global variable for them.

Once you have done that, add this method to make your code shorter:

```
-(void)changeView:(NSArray *)strArray {
    NSArray *viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, nil];
    for (int a = 0; 0 < 3; a++) {
        UIImageView *img = viewArray[a];
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:strArray[a]];
        [img setNeedsDisplay]; // If you really want to do this.
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
[self changeView:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Image_for_img1.suffix", @"Image_for_img2.suffix", @"Image_for_img3.suffix", nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, currentNetworkDelayTime is set by me to test the below code, I know this. I tried ur answer, like changeView method, but the imageView still not updated.

Comment: Have you created the objects? Ex. in viewDidLoad, img = [[UIIMageView alloc] init]; or in storyboard.

Comment: And I see now that you don't enter the suffix for the image ".jpg".

Comment: currentNetworkDelayTime == naming implies this is the network delay and not related to how often the timer runs. about the views: sound advice

Comment: @Arbitur  YES, I created the objects. BTW, I tried add the extension of the image file, such as ".png", But it remains not work. I think, Maybe not the problem of suffix.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks for ur help, the timer will runs every one second.

Comment: Who CAN GIVE ME SOME HELP, THIS PROBLEM CONFUSED ME FOR 2 DAYS.

Comment: If you have done what I said you need to remove the removeAllSubviews, and why are you doing everything in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()?
And what is this .left and .right?

Comment: Now, I changed my code according to your help, Now I set the view frame and location previously, and in the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), I just set the image to the UIImageView, but this does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on my computer and I got it working.

In Header file:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImageView *networkStatusImageView;
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(test) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
self.networkStatusImageView = [self networkStatusImageView];
[self.view addSubview:self.networkStatusImageView];
```

function networkStatusImageView:

```
- (UIImageView *)networkStatusImageView
{
if (nil == _networkStatusImageView) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
    _networkStatusImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    _networkStatusImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight | UIViewContentModeTop;

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100*a, 0, 100, 50)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [_networkStatusImageView addSubview:img];
}
}
return _networkStatusImageView;
}
```

function test:

```
-(void)test {
int currentNetworkDelayTime = 0;
BOOL currentISRed = NO;
NSArray *subViews = [self.networkStatusImageView subviews];
UIImageView *img1 = [subViews objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView *img2 = [subViews objectAtIndex:1];
UIImageView *img3 = [subViews objectAtIndex:2];
if (currentNetworkDelayTime == 0) {
    if (currentISRed) {
        [img1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [img2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [img3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    } else {
        [img1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [img2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [img3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
}
```

I used background color instead of images because I didn't want to make images for testing this, just change it to `setImage:` and it should work.

Comment: Arbitur, Thanks for your help, Maybe there is something different. I did not put the view in UIViewController. I made a customized UIView and put these image into it. see.

Comment: @interface RHCVoIPCardView : UIButton

Comment: It doesnt have to be inside only the viewDidLoad, it can also be inside initWithFrame:.

Comment: OK, I have another question, what will be called when UIView disappeared? Like viewDidUnload will be called when a UIViewController disappeared.

Comment: I have tried ur solution, but just work at first time, when the view appeared again, the solution will not work any more. I think there are something cached, now the view implementation is using ARC. When the view disappeared, I just call [self removeFromSuperView];

Comment: Im not really sure what you want to achieve. Do you want a button that has 3 images in it or something else?

Comment: If you want to remove the networkStatusImageView call [networkStatusImageView removeFromSuperView];

Comment: I just want to implement a dail and receive call view, A customized view hold plenty of UIViews. the networkStatusView is one of them.

Comment: I have solved my problem, see the new answer, Thanks very much, Arbitur. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem, solution below:

I checked the problem carefully and I create three UIImage field var. below:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *imgFile1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *imgFile2;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *imgFile3;
```

and link them with the xib image resource.

This implementation of the feature is not good and I plan to re-implement 
 it next version, there is too much memory allocation and release, some allocation and release can be removed to make the code more efficient.

Thanks all the guys help me.

Comment: seems esoteric to me Im afraid.. arc not releasing stuff affecting UI :) it must be something else